# Same namespaces used by 2 vendor packages: laravel and lumen

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, composer-php, lumen

In my project we have both Laravel and Lumen being installed by a single composer.json. Laravel for a web project, Lumen for an API, both of which are part of the same 'project'.

So in the 'vendor' folder I have the following files:

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

and

vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Foundation/Support/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

Now both of these use the same namespace:

Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider

In one of our classes I do:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

The problem is that both packages in the 'vendor' folder use this namespace, yet the files and methods within the files are different.

Is there anyway to explicitly specify which version of the namespace we use? Or add an alias to one of them?

Obviously I can't change the packages because 'composer update' would override them.

Any ideas welcomed. Thanks

Comment: The `use` command is specific to the file it appears in, so I am not sure I can see what the problem is. Can you explain how this issue is manifesting itself - do you get an error? When you say "this namespace", do you mean `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider`? If so, only one package will use that - that's the point of namespaces.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you saying that there is a class "Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider" in both Laravel and Lumen folder?

Comment: I've added more clarity to the question

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using Laravel *and* Lumen in the same application?

Comment: I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different namespaces (not one) containing two classes with the same name. Just use two alliases:

```
use Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/EventServiceProvider as IlluminateEventServiceProvider;
use Foundation/Support/Providers/EventServiceProvider as LumenEventServiceProvider;
```

From here you will be able to call both classes without ambiguity.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't help. You're inventing your own namespace in the code you've provided (the second one).

Comment: The pattern I used above is usually the way namespaces are constructed. After searching through the laravel codebase on github I see what you mean. This is an oversight on there part. The namespaces should be as I describe above.

Comment: Correct. Got in touch the with creators of Laravel and Lumen and they said it's not possible to use them side-by-side. Thanks though.